# Mod-rewrite and php not working in in get method

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Having problem in mod-rewrite .HTACCESS and php.
I have a page name `users.php` this page display selected user and my normal link is like this `users.php?member=John` then i changed it to clean url like this `users/member/John` but my problem is when you visit the page using normal url it will work fine but now i have rewrite it in my .HTACCESS it will take me to user page but not information will display it will be empty

**Here is my .HTACCESS**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+users\.php\?member=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ users/member/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^users/member/([^/]+)/?$ users.php?member=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**HERE IS MY PHP CODE**

```
<?php

  if(isset($_GET['member'])) { 


include($root . '_inc/dbconn.php');

try{

      $db_conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
      $db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $stmtData = $db_conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:getmember ");
      $stmtData->bindParam(":getmember", $_GET['member']);
      $stmtData->execute();

    $UserData = $stmtData->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if ($UserData) {
         $Dusername  = $UserData->username;
         $Dphoto = $UserData->photo;
         $Demail = $UserData->email;

      }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
    }
$db_conn = null;
}

?>
<?php echo $Dusername;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `RewriteCond`. You have to negate the condition (note the '!' sign):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+users\.php\?member=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^users/member/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^users/member/([^/]+)/?$ users.php?member=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You can test your Rewrite Rules on [online htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Comment: is still the same thing